# Mage_Sales_Model_Quote override

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, overrides

I've over-ridden the `validateMinimumAmount` function from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote in my own Model file (Quote.php).  Here, I'm applying additional logic for Customer Groups.  On the first order, they have a set minimum order value, and on subsequent orders, they have a different minimum order value.

This appears to be working exactly how I expected, however, it has a knock-on affect that a message is displayed on the cart page.  This message includes the value from the admin system (`sales/minimum_order/amount`) - but this isn't the value I'm checking against, and `sales/minimum_order/active` is set to false.

This appears to be coming from `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` line 147.  It doesn't additionally check if sales/minimum_order/active is active or not before adding the message.

Is there any way I can remove this message or change the value passed to it?

Comment: override the controller and add an if statement around that message or remove it completely.  or even better, add your own value in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marius's advice echo'd my own original thoughts, I over-rode the CartController.php

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Module before="Mage_Checkout">Namespace_Module</Namespace_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Then CartController - app/code/community/Namespace/Module/controllers/CartController.php

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS
    . 'CartController.php';

class Namespace_Module_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I can only accept it from tomorrow :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice :)